Google Sheets - importrange function - showing or hiding data based on user permissions
End result is to have one Google Sheet containing multiple tabs, whereby person 1 has view access to tab A, and person 2 has view access to tab B, but they are unable to view the other's tabs. And then there is person 3 who has view access to both tab A as well as tab B.
The protection available in Google Sheets restricts edit access, but not view access.
I was wondering if someone has cracked this, and has a way to do it, possibly with the importrange.
I can share the sheets if it will help, but for the moment I am curious if this is even possible at all.
Thank you.
